# Why I get 500 internal server error in asp.net core hosted in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I published my **.Net core** web to IIS in localhost.
In my code I use HttpClient.GetAsync to retrieve information from external resource.
The HttpClientHandler is configured with '**UseDefaultCredentials = true**'.
Everything is working fine when running under IISEXPRESS. In IIS I get 500 'internal server error' on response from HttpClient.GetAsync

Installed the host bundle and tried many things but nothing worked.

Help please!

Comment: I would start with getting more details about this 500. If its localhost you should get page that gives more details telling you in which line error happens and what was the specific exception. If thats only thing you have, maybe look on Windows Event Viewer if there is some Error Reported by ASp.Net with more details.

Comment: Expected as so many differences are there, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Have you checked IIS logs?

Comment: You can run your application in debug mode in IIS using Visual Studio. You can also enable logging as per this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/logging-and-diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0); remember to create Log directory as IIS will not create it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Alex and RedgoodBreaker's suggestions. Their suggestions are correct, and the problem can be located quickly.

**1. Windows Event Viewer**

Open `Event Viewer` -> `Windows Logs` -> `Application`

**2. Log creation and redirection**

[Enhanced diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/logging-and-diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enhanced-diagnostic-logs)

**3. Enable Failed Request Tracing Settings**

Offical doc: [Using Failed Request Tracing Rules to Troubleshoot Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Still, the problem persists. Nothing comes up in any of the logs. I thought maybe it had something to do with windows authentication but couldn't find anything wrong with the app or iis configurations. I just get '500 internal server error' with no further explanation. And again this only happens when hosted on IIS. Would appreciate any more suggestions.

Comment: @DavidHershkovich have you solved it?